# Array issues in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to allow the user to enter up to 10 numbers, I have my code working without the array but the second I try to incorporate my array I get the error message

"error: invalid operands to binary / (have 'int *' and 'int')
:27:7: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
.c:34:13: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
.c:37:12: error: invalid operands to binary / (have 'int *' and 'int')
.c:39:10: warning: comparison between pointer and integer

I've declared the array on each line and it's still a problem.. Do I need to change the variable types and make sure they're in unison. I'm very confused ..

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    sum_divisors();
}


int sum_divisors ()
{
#define SIZE 10
    int i, t; /* the j variable will be your a/i in the loop below */
    long sum = 1;


    int j;
    int a [SIZE];
    printf("Enter in a number \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    sum = 1;
    i=2;
    j=a/i;

    if (a < 2){

        return 0;

    }
    while (i < j) /* loop until i is greater than or equal to sqrt(a), meaning i >= a/i */
    {
        if (i*j == a) /* Here's the divisibility test. If i*j == a, then they are both divisors */
            sum += i+j; /* add both to the sum */
        i = i+1; /* Advance to the next i value */
        j = a/i; /* and find the corresponding j value */
    }
    if (i*i == a) /* test for a perfect square here */
        sum += i;
    printf(" The Sum of the number is" " %ld", sum);
}
```

Comment: You need to read more about arrays in C. `int a [SIZE];` and then `scanf("%d", &a);`?

Comment: what is/was your intention with `j=a/i;`

Comment: @WhozCraig        I was trying to find the corresponding value of j .. other than my array the program functions the way I need it to so there is nothing wrong with my code despite the array issue

Comment: Ah.. ok. Its just a familiarity with how arrays are used in the language, or it appears. its certainly inline-commented enough, just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Actually what is your requirement here...?

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR   I'm taking user input for up to 10 values, the printing the sum of it's divisors and example would be                                           The input 4: 4x1=4 and 2x2=4 the divisors other than itself are 2 and 1 so 2+1=3. Output is 3. The input 5: 5x1=5 the only divisors of a prime number are itself and 1. Output is a 1.
The input 6: 6x1=6 and 3x2=6 the divisors other than itself are 1, 2 and 3. Output is 6=1+2+3. The input 12: 12x1=12 and 6x2=12 and 3x4=12. Output=16=1+6+2+3+4.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an *array* `a`, you refer to its individual *elements* as `a[x]`, where `x` is the array index.

So, to read in the fourth element, you would use something like:

```
scanf ("%d", &(a[3])); // should really check return code here as well.
```

In your code, you're continuously referring to `a`, which generally decays to the *address of the first element* of the array `a`, not something you should be doing if you want the actual elements themselves.

It's that decaying to an address which is causing the pointer/integer conflict.

Answer (score 0):

An element of an array `int a[SIZE]` is to be accessed as `a[i]` or as `*(a+i)` with `i` as the index, not simply `a`. `a` points to the base address of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The line `scanf("%d", &a);`, `a` is the array name which is a constant integer pointer. With this line you are trying to modify a constant variable. That is why it shows the above error.

To take input into array use following code

```
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]); //a[i] will represent the i+1 the element in the array
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one....

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
sum_divisors();
}


int sum_divisors ()
{
    #define SIZE 10
int i, t; /* the j variable will be your a/i in the loop below */
long sum = 1;
int j,div;
int a [SIZE];
printf("Enter 10 number \n");

     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
        printf("a[%d]=>",i);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    div=a[i]/2;
    sum=1;

            if(a[i]<2)
            sum=0;
            else
            {
            for(j=2;j<=div;j++)
            if((a[i]%j)==0)
            sum+=j;
            }
    printf(" The Sum of divisor of %d is %ld\n", a[i],sum);
    }

 }
```